# Загрузка фотографии в фотоальбом пользователя со стороннего сайта

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api, изображения

Надо сделать загрузку фотографии в фотоальбом пользователя со стороннего сайта.
Open api vk.

С чего начать, может дадите ссылку на урок?

Почему не работает следующее?

```
VK.init({apiId: 3012101, onlyWidgets: true}); VK.Auth.login( null, VK.access.PHOTO | VK.access.FRIENDS);

$(document).ready(function() { VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(function(response) { // берем его id var id = response.session.mid;
    VK.Api.call('photos.createAlbum', {title: 'Имя_альбома',privacy: '0', comment_privacy: '0',description: 'блаблабла'});

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Покурите [документацию ВК по Open API](http://vk.com/developers.php?o=-1&p=Open_API&s=0). Наверное, код создания альбома нужно ставить в коллбэк после авторизации, а у вас там Null пока.